is there a way to make kinematic rigidbodies respect collisions?
I'm dabbling in making some games in unity to learn the ropes so I can work on a single project eventually and make it good enough for my standards (if it's foolish the expect that or not is another subject)
anyway I'm making a 2d platformer now, and I have a very specific feeling in mind for the movement. I attempted to implement it myself and succeeded, with drag and gravity and all that, but I had trouble with implementing collisions. I used a raycast to check if the player is grounded and just set my velocity var to 0 when it's grounded, but sometimes it'd just phase through the ground and get stuck in the middle, sometimes it'd phase completely through, and it just wasn't consistent.
because I want my character to be completely moved by my implementation of movement, I made it kinematic because that's from what I've heard is the most fit for movement that's largely defined by code, but I wanted to hijack the collision functionality of the physics simulation while ignoring the other parts, but when I let my object fall onto a static rigidbody, it completely ignored the collision (I did turn on "use full kinematic contact"), not affecting the velocity at all
sorry for the story behind it I just wanted to get my cause across. basically I want to define all of the movement of the body on my own through code, but I want it to still respect collisions to not allow it to pass through ground. if there's a better solution, like using dynamic bodies or working on my own full collision system, I'd like to hear them.
here's the code I made in another project to try and get to the bottom of why it wasn't working
it's not much but that's what it is

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movementtest : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float maxSpeed = 10f;
    public float accel = 1f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.y < maxSpeed){
            rb.velocity += Vector2.down * accel * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
    }
}


if I misunderstood the use of kinematic or something like that, I'd be happy to learn. as a last line to make sure my goal is clear; I want to define the movement of the body completely on my own, apart from 1 part: collision. I want the body to respect collisions as in not clip through other colliders, but still retain only my definitions for movement. I have a feeling that I'm missing a very big part of the picture so enlighten me

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.
If you want more realistic movement with gravity, forces etc... then you should use a dynamic rigidbody, and control it either by applying forces to it, or directly by editing its velocity as you're doing.
I'm currently working on a game with a player running around, and i did this. My player object has a rigidbody attached with kinematic turned off, and my code sets its velocity when im performing actions. For example :
// Calculate the movement direction based on input and camera orientation
Vector3 moveDirection = cameraForward * moveInputs.y + cameraRight * moveInputs.x;
Vector3 aimDirection = cameraForward * lookInputs.y + cameraRight * lookInputs.x;

// Apply movement to the player
rb.velocity = new Vector3(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y, moveDirection.z * moveSpeed);

This way, player is still affected by gravity and other forces that could make the game more realistic (for example an explosion, force fields etc...) but i can still control it through code.
An other option wouldve been to use rigibody.AddForce() to make it move, but it makes really hard to control the speed of the player, as it increases over time as forces are getting combined each frame, and then is hard to get slowed down. (would be perfect for a rolling ball game for example)
Basically, kinematic objects arent affected by forces, while dynamic are. So if you dont plan your controller to be affected by any forces (explosions, ragdolls, impacts ...) you should go for a kinematic object, but then control it using rigibody.MovePosition instead of affecting velocity.
Also, if you want to control a player without being affected by forces, then i would recommand you to use a CharacterController component instead, as kinematic objects dont get collisions from all other rigidbodies (especially static ones)
In summary, it all depends on what you really want to achieve :)

I kinda stated exactly what I wanted to achieve but ok; anyway I just set it to dynamic and turned off gravity and set its mass to 0 and all that so I'll control exactly how it behaves each frame except for collisions

i know that you stated what you wanted, but its great to sometimes take a step aside that's why i wanted to give you a better overview of allt he possibilites, as for me using a dynamic rigidbody with a mass of 0 (behaving exactly like a character controller component then) is useless as u are not using any of the properties of the component. but feel free to do whatever you want my man, there are no wrong approaches.

what's a character controller? I haven't been using tutorials, trusting my basic knowledge of c# and gamedev to guide me, so whatever I use is just what I stumble upon. I'll look into it, thanks

A character controller is a component (such as colliders, rigidbody, camera etc) that you can attach to a gameobject, and use it to move the object through functions adapted to character movement. The nice thing is that it handles player going on slopes up to a certain angle and a lot of other things but its really a different approach from what you are using so for now maybe stick to your setup but if you have some time i recommand checking some examples/explanations on youtube. I'm personnally not a big fan of this component but as i said it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.
